# Grails: use domain method in named query

Tags: grails, grails-orm

in my domain model, I have a method that does something with my data.

e.g.

```
class Person {

    String lastname
    String firstname

    String bigname() {
        return lastname.toUpperCase()
    }

    static namedQueries = {
        withBigname { name ->
            eq(this.bigname(), name)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to use this method like a property in the named query, but

```
this.bigname()
```

only throws a

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError
```

-Exception.

Does anyone know how to use domain methods in criteria and named queries?

---

Update: I now tried this:

```
class Person {

    String lastname
    String firstname
    String bigname

    static transients = [ 'bigname' ]

    def getBigname() {
        return lastname.toUpperCase()
    }

    static namedQueries = {
        withBigname { name ->
            eq('bigname', name)
        }
    }
}
```

But it only results in a "could not resolve property: bigname"-exception...

Comment: You are trying to query a transient field, remove the String bigname or remove the transient and getBigname method to allow querying. Read the docs, it seems you don't have a clear idea of the transient usage.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use class methods in queries, because queries are actually translated to SQL.

You might be able to get what you need by using writing the complexity in SQL a "SQL Restriction". Search for "SQL Restriction" on http://grails.org/doc/2.0.x/guide/GORM.html

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Try to name the method in [JavaBean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBean) getter and setter notation.
Rename method `bigname()` to `getBigname()`.

Answer (score 0):

On a static closure, you don't have a `this`.  You'll either need to store the `bigname` in the Database, do some sort of case insensitive criteria.

Answer (score -1):

looks like you are trying to accomplish this:

```
class Person {

  String lastname
  String firstname

  static namedQueries = {
      withName { name ->
          eq('lastname', name, [ignoreCase: true])
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: sorry, this was only an example. the real task is far more complex.